# Forge MarkupUtils renderToCanvas with multiple layers?

Tags: autodesk-forge, markup, autodesk

We currently have a PDF loaded into Forge viewer with multiple markup layers (created using a custom DrawMode), each layers visibility toggleable.

We want to give the user the ability of printing what they currently see (the PDF with the layered markup). I was able to find posts offering potential solutions for printing (using canvas, getScreenshot and MarkupUtils renderToCanvas).
Example post: [Autodesk Forge get screenshot with markups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352194/autodesk-forge-get-screenshot-with-markups)

The solution at first looked to be working great but I've noticed only one of our markup layers is ever rendered to the canvas (seemingly the last one added), the other layers are ignored.

All markups are loaded and are visible on screen. Additionally if I hide that layer, it is still printed.

Is there any way to add the markup from all loaded markup layers using renderToCanvas?
Or any potential known workaround?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Code snippet of the function I've wrote which works (but loading the most recently added layer only).

```
export const printViewerToPDF = (markupsCore: MarkupsCore, jsPDF: any) => {
    // Create new image
    var screenshot = new Image();

    // Get the canvas element
    var canvas = document.getElementById('snapshot') as HTMLCanvasElement;

    // Fit canvas to match viewer
    if (canvas) {
        canvas.width = markupsCore.bounds.width;
        canvas.height = markupsCore.bounds.height;

        // Create a context
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Clear
        if (ctx) {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }

        // Screenshot viewer and render to canvas
        markupsCore.viewer.getScreenShot(canvas.width, canvas.height, function(
            blobUrl: any,
        ) {
            screenshot.onload = function() {
                if (ctx) {
                    ctx.drawImage(screenshot, 0, 0);
                }
            };

            screenshot.src = blobUrl;
        });

        // Render markup to canvas
        setTimeout(function() {
            markupsCore.renderToCanvas(ctx, function() {
                var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'px', [canvas.height, canvas.width]);
                pdf.addImage(ctx!.canvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                pdf.save(Date.now().toString() + '.pdf');
            });
        }, 300);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the `renderToCanvas` method looks like (you can find it in https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/extensions/Markup/Markup.js):

```js
MarkupsCore.prototype.renderToCanvas = function(context, callback, renderAllMarkups) {

        var width = this.bounds.width;
        var height = this.bounds.height;
        var viewBox = this.getSvgViewBox(width, height);
        var numberOfScreenshotsTaken = 0;
        var markups = [];
        var layer;

        var onMarkupScreenshotTaken = function () {
            if (callback && (++numberOfScreenshotsTaken === markups.length)) {
                callback();
            }
        }.bind(this);

        if (renderAllMarkups) {
            var svgKeys = Object.keys(this.svg.childNodes);
            var layersKeys = Object.keys(this.svgLayersMap);

            // Append only markups that their parent layer is contained inside the svg main container.
            for (var i = 0; i < svgKeys.length; i++) {                
                for (var j = 0; j < layersKeys.length; j++) {
                    layer = this.svgLayersMap[layersKeys[j]];
                    if (this.svg.childNodes[svgKeys[i]] === layer.svg) {
                        markups = markups.concat(layer.markups);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            layer = this.svgLayersMap[this.activeLayer] || this.editModeSvgLayerNode;
            markups = layer.markups;
        }

        if (markups.length === 0) {
            callback();
        } else {
            markups.forEach(function(markup) {
                markup.renderToCanvas(context, viewBox, width, height, onMarkupScreenshotTaken);
            });
        }
    };
```

As you can see, if you leave the 3rd parameter undefined or set to `false`, only markups from the *active* layer will be rendered. If you set the 3rd parameter to `true`, markups from all layers should be rendered.

Try stepping into the method yourself and double-check the list of markups towards the end, before `markup.renderToCanvas` is called for every item in the list.

Comment: Can't believe I've missed that, the links are super useful. I've added true as a third param and all are showing! Really appreciate your time, just finding my way in this realm. Thanks again.