# Autodesk Forge - Viewer (markup extension) screenshots is reverted on iOS

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have an app with Forge Viewer there is an installed markup extension. There is the same implementation as in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60369589). Everything works good, but I've faced a problem that markups are upside down on screenshots if I use Ipad. Look at screenshot, there should be a line from top-left to right-bottom in the source. The same result is in both orientations.

[screenshot result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldCgP.png)

I've tried to use a new method, but it didn't help.

```
viewer.impl.getScreenShotProgressive
```

I've also posted it to the bug report, but probably there is some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a potential bug in the Viewer API. Please send your information (repro steps, viewer version, OS version, etc.) to `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and we will pass the info to our engineering team.