# How to export markups created for Inventor (drawing/part/assembly) file to PDF from viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have created a markup extension in the autodesk viewer. Is it possible to export a markup to PDF using APIs.

The online viewer from Autodesk has Print button which looks to be calling window.print(). Is this the way to print the drawing to PDF?
In the viewer from "Comments" I open a specific markup and ("view markup" window) click "Print" and it prints drawing without markups.

The button "Export" under "Comments" is exporting all the markups into a single PDF file. How do we do this using forge APIs.

Is it possible to print only selected a markup instead of all the markups.?

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official/supported way of doing this using the Viewer APIs but you might be able to get markups "baked" into a PDF by combining multiple features/libraries:

- the Markups extension in Forge Viewer allows you to render the markups into a PNG file; see this Stack Overflow answer: [Autodesk Forge get screenshot with markups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352194/autodesk-forge-get-screenshot-with-markups)
- there are 3rd party libraries that allow you to insert semi-transparent PNG images into PDFs, for example *pdfkit*: https://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html
- since the Markups extension uses an `<svg>` element under the hood, you should also be able to hide any of the SVG elements you don't want included in the PNG